# Genus of complete 4-partite graph.

Tags: graph-theory

What is the genus of the graph $K_{mn,n,n,n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers? I know that the genus of the graph $K_{mn,n,n}$ (see A. T. white, Graphs, Groups and Surfaces, Theorem 6-39) is given by the formula $\gamma(K_{mn,n,n})=\frac{(mn-2)(n-1)}{2}$. I just wonder whether someone has found the formula for the genus of $K_{mn,n,n,n}$ or not. Thanks in advance.